# node-maxmind usage for streaming data with IP address

Tags: node.js, node-modules, fs, maxmind

I have streaming data coming in with IP address. I want to translate the IP to longitude and latitude before putting the data into my database.

This is what I was doing but it is causing some issues. I also tried putting locationObject outside the for loop. That weirdly is using a lot of memory. I know this is blocking code but it should be fast. Though I see memory issue as data object is coming from a stream continuously ans each data object is huge.

```
for (var i ==0; i < data.length; i++){
        if (data.client_ip !== null) {
            var locationLookup = maxmind.openSync('./GeoIP2-City.mmdb');
            var ip = data.client_ip;
            var maxmindObj = locationLookup.get(ip);
            locationObject.country = maxmindObj.country.names.en;
            locationObject.latitude = maxmindObj.location.latitude;
            locationObject.longitude = maxmindObj.location.longitude;
           }
}
```

Again trying to put maxmind.openSync('./GeoIP2-City.mmdb'); outside fr loop is causing huge increase in memory.

The Other option is to use nonblocking code

```
maxmind.open('/path/to/GeoLite2-City.mmdb', (err, cityLookup) => {
  var city = cityLookup.get('66.6.44.4');
});
```

But I don't think this is a good dea to put this inside a loop.

How can I handle this? I am getting data object every minute

https://github.com/runk/node-maxmind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think reading the database file for each iteration of the loop would be fast ("blocking code" doesn't equal "fast code"), it's much better to read the database file once and then loop over `data`.

`maxmind.openSync()` will read the entire database into memory, which is mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/runk/node-maxmind#usage):

> Be careful with sync version! Since mmdb files are quite large
>   (city database is about 100Mb) `fs.readFileSync` blocks whole
>   process while it reads file into buffer.

If you don't have memory to spare, the only other option would be to open the file asynchronously. Again, not inside the loop, but outside of it:

```
maxmind.open("./GeoIP2-City.mmdb", (err, locationLookup) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data.client_ip !== null) {
      var ip = data.client_ip;
      var maxmindObj = locationLookup.get(ip);
      locationObject.country = maxmindObj.country.names.en;
      locationObject.latitude = maxmindObj.location.latitude;
      locationObject.longitude = maxmindObj.location.longitude;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting. The problem with this again for me is that I have multiple times this function will be called. I am getting data object at a very high rate (stream of data every minute). Every time a data object is received I parse all the fields in the loop including IP. That means every time again the file will be opened. Is there any other way to query maxmind without using the file? maxmind.openSync() will read the entire database into memory. I have 100mb on my instance but the problem is when I run it with pm2 the memory keeps on increasing. Not sure GC runs cleanup

Comment: No matter which solution you're going to chose, you should open/read the database just once. If the function gets called a lot, and you want to open the database file asynchronously, you should open it outside of your function. It depends on your application structure what the best solution would be.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. Let me do some trials and test. Monitor the memory etc and get back to you with the results

Comment: did some tests. Figured out that your solution is definitely the best way to handle my use case. The Garbage collectors work properly and the memory stays in control if I open it outside the loop async.

Comment: can u take a look at the answer I posted and tell me how to handle that in a better way. Appreciate your help on this. Your solution works fine but I just want to be sure that I am ready for the long-run.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I am worried is over time I call this function so many times. every time my consumers read jsonObject from kakfa (happening every minute). is there a much better way to optimize that as well. so I call this function every minute. How can I better optimize this further

```
function processData(jsonObject) {
    maxmind.open('./GeoIP2-City.mmdb', function(err, locationLookup) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error('something went wrong on maxmind fetch', err);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) { ...}
})
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend opening the file each time the function gets called: open it once, when your app starts, and pass `locationLookup` around.

Comment: That sounds good. Made the changes and working well now. Thanks for all your help and feedback. It was very helpful.